# SQL get aggregate value within a time-window in a time-series table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to write a SQL method in Python using SQLite/sqlalchemy to build a new table containing the analyzed data like mean, median, max, var over a certain period of time, based on another table which contains the raw time-series data.

Let's say the raw data is  and the timestamp is not evenly distributed. I want to get another table:  from the raw data table, which is basically the aggregate value over a 60-second sliding time window, e.g.:

```
RAW:
TIME      VALUE
11:11:12   12
11:11:22   24
11:11:34   16
11:12:21   18
11:12:45   22
11:13:03   15
```

And I want to get:

```
ID  WINDOW_TIME      MEAN            MEDIAN         MAX       VAR
1      11:11    mean(12,24,16)   med(12,24,16) ...
2      11:12    mean(18,22)      ...
3      11:13    ...
...
```

How could I group the data according to timestamp?

Comment: tag the question with only one database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `TIME` column is of time type (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) you could do something like this in your group by.

```
GROUP BY TIME_FORMAT(`TIME`, '%H:%i')
```

If, on the other hand, the column is just a string type, things are a little trickier.  I suppose, if you can guarantee every value is in the format hh:ii:ss, you could use `SUBSTRING`.

```
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(`TIME` FROM 1 FOR 5)
```

If you go with either of these options, however, I really hope, for your sake, that you have a paucity of records in your database because I'm pretty sure each of these options is going to be terrible in terms of performance.  I haven't done extensive tests, but I don't think mysql is going to be able to use indexes on either example.

Honestly, you're probably better off creating a table which contains time as hh:ii for each record, and then using that table for your aggregate queries, than you are trying to do this in all one query.

Comment: Thank you, man! I will try to just store the hh:mm as time-stamp then, the poor performance makes sense